# Phonological Trees: Consonant Gemination in tikz-qtree

Tags: tikz-trees, trees, linguistics, tikz-qtree

I am new at this. I am making phonological trees.

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tipa}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\tikzset{frontier/.style={distance from root=100pt}}
\Tree
[.$\omega$
[.$\sigma$ k [.$\mu$ i ] [.$\mu$ \node(a){t}; ] ]
[.\node(b){$\sigma$};  [.$\mu$ e ] ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

\draw (b.south) -- (a.north);

\end{document}
```

I want to be able to connect the second sigma to the third letter "t". I tried to make the "t" a node and the second "sigma" a node and then draw a line between them, but it yielded this:

[image]

How can I draw a line between the second sigma and the "t"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the `\draw` command inside the `tikzpicture`?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tipa}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\tikzset{frontier/.style={distance from root=100pt}}
\Tree
[.$\omega$
[.$\sigma$ k [.$\mu$ i ] [.$\mu$ \node(a){t}; ] ]
[.\node(b){$\sigma$};  [.$\mu$ e ] ] ]
\draw (b.south) -- (a.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Ben You're welcome, to tell the truth, you already did all by yourself, only the position of the command was wrong! :) Thank you for accepting my answer!